# turn on the switched off phone programatically and send a message at a particular time.Is it possible?

Tags: android

I am doing a project in which i have to send a message at a particular time.that function is already in many mobile apps.But what i want is even if the mobile is switch off,i want to turn it on programatically at a particular time and send the message .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` with an `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm to get control at your specified time. Have the `AlarmManager` trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` via the `PendingIntent` you use when setting up the alarm in `AlarmManager`. Have the `BroadcastReceiver` send the message.